# wp_query loop with compare operator simply not working, why?

Tags: wp-query

Frustrated and would love some help with this.

I have a custom post field titled 'expire_date'. When the expire date is reached, I want that post to to drop off of the list of posts that are returned.

I use Generate Blocks, and support at Generate Press were kind enough to give me some code that they say should work for what I want.

However, it doesn't. None of the posts I want filtered out are filtered out.

I've tested the 'if' statement and that query_args do work by using a different query_arg. It worked fine (and is included in the script below).

But the actual script that I need to work doesn't. I've tested every way that I can think of, double checked the custom field and it's working and titled correctly. I've changed the comparison operator to = and even tried != and it doesn't make any difference. Nothing is filtered out. Why?

Thanks for any help!

Chris

```php
add_filter( 'generateblocks_query_loop_args', function( $query_args, $attributes ) {
    if (
        ! is_admin()
        && ! empty( $attributes['className'] )
        && strpos( $attributes['className'], 'my-query' ) !== false
    ) {
        // pass meta_query parameter
        $query_args[ 'meta_query' ] = array(
            'meta_key'          => 'expire_date', //example 2022-06-20
            'meta_value'        => date("Y-m-d"),
            'type'              => 'DATE', //have also tried DATETIME and TIME
            'meta_compare'      => '>=',
        );
        ////in testing, this works/// $query_args['date_query'] = array( 'after' => '2022-06-01' );
    }
    return $query_args;
}, 10, 2 );
```

Comment: I fixed the indentation but the code says is that you want all posts that have an expire date that is newer than the current date ( `>=` higher or equal to/ present and future ). `meta_query` is normally meant to indicate what you want, not what you don't want. I do see though that this is a generateblocks question, you need to go back to their support route, or ask other generatepress/generateblock users in their communities. 3rd party plugin/theme dev support questions are offtopic here

Comment: Thank you for fixing the formatting Tom, I did not realize it was messed up when I posted. I don't think this is specific to generatepress/generateblock though - the query args are wp, correct? I could be wrong. I did try = and != as comparison operators, just to test. I still got everything unfiltered. It's like the query args aren't being applied at all...

Comment: Not sure this is your issue but saw this note in the docs "The 'meta_key', 'meta_value', 'meta_type' and 'meta_compare' arguments will only work if you use the second method described below."  https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_meta_query/  If you are using that method should `type` also be `meta_type` ?

Comment: possible, but that doesn't mean they are, or that generatepress/generateblock doesn't do things to them, or has special semantics. You would need to ask someone familiar with it to know, hence the concern that it is off-topic. We could pretend it's the `pre_get_posts` filter, but it is not, and you have no guarantee that it would work if we did. That's ignoring `$attributes`. Eitherway it's sophistry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[As stated in the documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#custom-field-post-meta-parameters): <sub>(bold formatting was added by me)</sub>

> Note that meta_query expects **nested arrays**, even if you only have
> one query.

So your meta query should actually look like the following, and note that in a `meta_query`, we don't use the `meta_` prefix, e.g. we use just `key` and not `meta_key`:

```php
$query_args['meta_query'] = array(
    array( // clause/query 1
        'key'     => 'expire_date',
        'value'   => date("Y-m-d"),
        'type'    => 'DATE',
        'compare' => '>=',
    )
);
```

Or use the root `meta_xxx` arguments instead, and note that I used `meta_type` instead of just `type`:

```php
$query_args['meta_key']     = 'expire_date';
$query_args['meta_value']   = date("Y-m-d");
$query_args['meta_type']    = 'DATE';
$query_args['meta_compare'] = '>=';
```

Or did you actually mean to use `$query_args['meta_query'][]` (note the `[]`), i.e. to add another clause to the existing `meta_query` array? But even so, make sure you use the correct *array keys*.

Comment: a reading of the generatepress code implies this is indeed the answer, but only assuming the `$attributes` conditions are reliable

Comment: @TomJNowell I actually focused straight on his meta query code and the `this works` comment, so I didn't notice that `$attributes` part.. (which sounds like the attributes of a dynamic block?) and your comment made me think that he might need to use another hook in the plugin which specifically used to modify the meta query, however I posted this answer mainly so that he knows the proper meta query formats. (edit: I forgot to tag you, so I reposted this comment..)

Comment: That did the trick Sally CJ, thank you very much, and for your help and sharing your knowledge too Tom (had to look up 'sophistry')